# Does selecting rows into a table variable prevent cursor locks on the source table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got a couple of reports that I have found need to be assembled row by row via cursor.

I know that cursors are not typically a good thing when run against tables, but if I were to create a cursor for a table variable would that prevent the row locks that could occur?  I've found ways to avoid cursors altogether in most cases but have not seen a way around it for a couple of reports.

Answer (score 0):

The reason cursors are bad is because of their atrocious performance, not typically because they cause locking (although that can certainly be an issue). If you use a cursor on a table variable, performance problems don't go away and locking still happens, but on the table variable table. The only difference is that a table variable cannot be accessed by other sessions, so they're guaranteed not to block on it, which is something. Overall performance will probably still drop because you need to copy data to the table variable first, but if your main concern is locks, sure, it can help.